# Include specific acronyms in acronym list without using them in-text

Tags: acronyms

I use the `acronym` package to automatically generate a list of acronyms, with the `onlyused` option.

Now there are a handful of acronyms which are never called with `\ac..{}` in-text, because they only appear inside graphs. Is there a way of forcing these to be marked as used so that they are included in the acronym list as though I had called them with `\ac{}`?

I have tried using `\acused{xyz}` but this only marks them in such a way that the short form is used afterwards; without following up with another `\ac{xyz}` they do not appear in the acronym list.

I have also tried putting them inside `\phantom{}`. They are allocated the appropriate spacing, but do not appear in the acronym list if I do this.

Is there any way to get the desired result, without removing the `onlyused` option (as that would necessitate manually commenting out a lot of acronyms in the list)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\ac{CDMA} \acused{GSM}

\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
  \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
  \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
  \acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! I took the liberty of adding a MWE.

Comment: `\acronymused` (instead of `\acused`) seems to work. The former does not seem to be meant as user command (it is documented only in the implementation section) but I don't see why not…

Comment: Great. Yes, `\acronymused{}` does the trick. One thing I've noticed is that it only works if you call `\acronymused{...}` _before_ `\begin{acronym}`; it appears to have no effect after the acronym block itself. Thanks @clemens (also for adding the MWE).